# scala differences between 2 functions syntaxes

Tags: scala, function

I'm trying to understand the differences between these 2 syntaxes in scala and why they have not the same result.

> testVal

and

> testVal2

are not defined in the same way

```
object FunctionVsVal2 extends App {


  val testVal: () => Int = {
    val r = util.Random.nextInt
    () => r
  }

  val testVal2: () => Int = () => {
    val r = util.Random.nextInt
    r
  }

  println(testVal())
  println(testVal())

  println(testVal2())
  println(testVal2())
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

`testVal2` is a [lambda expression](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#anonymous-functions). Each time you call `testVal2()`, it evaluates

```
{
  val r = util.Random.nextInt
  r
}
```

and so returns a new value.

`testVal` is a [block expression](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#blocks). It calculates `r` first and then returns `() => r` (the last expression in the block), so each time you call `testVal()`, the same `r` is used.

Comment: if testVal2 is called each time why :  println(testVal2 eq testVal2) prints true ? I was expecting to be false

Comment: `testVal2 eq testVal2` checks that `testVal2` is the same object as `testVal2`. Why do you expect it not to be? It's unrelated to what happens when you _apply_ `testVal2` by writing `testVal2()`.

Comment: In both cases the body of the lambda, the part after `() =>`, is called each time you call `testVal1/2()`. The difference is what these bodies are; in `testVal1` it's just `r`, in `testVal2` it's `{ val r = util.Random.nextInt; r }`. Does this help more?